# Add Tooltip on DHtmlX Scheduler in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I have injected DHtmlX scheduler in my angularjs app with the help of this [Link](http://www.dhtmlx.com/blog/creating-event-calendar-with-dhtmlxscheduler-and-angularjs/). I have followed all the steps of the above link and it's working.

Now, I am trying to add tooltip in angular DHtmlX scheduler. I am referring this [Link](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/tooltips.html) for tooltip, Below function is working I have tested it by taking out the output in console

```
scheduler.templates.tooltip_text = function(start,end,event) {
    console.log("<b>Event:</b> "+event.text+"<br/><b>Start date:</b> "+
    format(start)+"<br/><b>End date:</b> "+format(end));
    return "<b>Event:</b> "+event.text+"<br/><b>Start date:</b> "+
    format(start)+"<br/><b>End date:</b> "+format(end);
};
```

But still it is not showing in the html page. I am not getting how and why.

please help out on this.
Any suggestion or help would be appreciated , thanks in advance

Comment: Everything seems ok with your code. I've checked the original dhtmlx demo and added tooltips there - it seemed working ok, here is the repo if you wanted to check
https://github.com/AlexKlimenkov/angular-scheduler-demo
Can you give a link to the app, or a download link to a full demo so i could check it?